# Template file in go app reading itself instead of js and css files

Tags: go

I've just starting learning go and I'm noodling around with web apps using the Google app engine. I've worked through the guestbook tutorial, and have now started my own project. The go part compiles just fine, but there's something strange happening when the template tries to render. It's able to render all the HTML, but I've added both CSS and JS, and the template is somehow reading in itself instead of the respective CSS and JS files. It's bizarre. I'm not sure it's a path problem (I would expect a 404).

This is the error I'm getting in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

And when I view the resource it's picking up for the js file, it's identical to the template. I've placed my js and css relative to the template folder, so I would expect it would find it:

```
app/
- templates/
- css/
- js/
```

So my script is called thusly in the template:

```
<script src="../js/main.js"></script>
```

How should I be structuring my JS and CSS resources (and later, images, and SASS/LESS)?

*Edit*

This is what I see in the source for Chrome devtools:

[image: screenshot of devtools]

Comment: So I've found this documentation that indicates that it needs to be explicitly declared in the app.yaml file:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig

Which I've done (and changed the path to absolute in the script element), but I still have the same error.

Comment: using devtools on chrome (or similar) can you check if main.js is loaded? Does it have the correct content type? if it's not too big can you post it here?

Comment: @DeanElbaz I've added a screenshot to show you what's happening (main.js is actual javascript, just a short little geolocation thing to find the user's lat/long).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻ Ah it was the app.yaml file. I had:

```
application: bedlington
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

But that first url handler catches all the things. So instead this solved the problem:

```
application: bedlington
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /
  script: _go_app

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

Now I don't know how to catch all the urls (or how to properly exclude resource folders), but it solves the initial problem.

Comment: So the solution to catching all the files is to move the - url: /.* handler to the bottom of the list of handlers. As the file is parsed, it will stop at the first match and not read in anything else.